# Restar dos valores de distintas tablas

Tags: sql

¿Cómo podría restar dos valores de distintas tablas en SQL? Quiero que en una columna reste los días libres que le quedan de vacaciones al usuario. Estos días tiene que ser la diferencia entre los días que ha pedido en las solicitudes y los días que dispone de vacaciones al año.

Tengo dos tablas:

- `solicitud`: que es una tabla de solicitud que tiene como campos `pk_solicitud`, `fk_empleado`, `n_diassolicitados`.
- `sec_users`: que es una tabla de usuarios con `pk_user`, `name`, `dias_disponibles`.

El `fk_empleado` de la tabla de solicitud es la clave foránea para `pk_user` de la tabla usuario.

Y he intentado esta consulta:

```
select u.dias_disponibles-s.N_DIASSOLICITADOS as dias_libres 
from solicitud s, sec_users u
```

---

Una vez que ya me muestra los dias libres de cada usuario por ejemplo así:

```
Usuario               Días libres
==============        ==========
Usuario 1                    10
Usuario 2                    12
Usuario 3                     8
Usuario 4                    11
```

Estoy intentado que el me salgan los días que sí ha solicitado. En la función anterior me marcaba los que no ha pedido pero ahora quiero los que sí ha pedido. Quedaría así:

```
Usuario             Vacaciones  Baja
==============    ============  ==== 
Usuario 1                10        1        
Usuario 2                12        0        
Usuario 3                 8        3        
Usuario 4                11        1
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que añadas la consulta SQL completa a tu pregunta, dándole a [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/141484/edit), mas información en [ask]

Comment: Si no usas el boton [edit] y agregas toda la informacion que se te pidio a la pregunta, esta va a terminar cerrada. Por favor evita agregar informacion en los comentarios.

Comment: @AlvaroRoman he editado la pregunta para añadir los datos de tus comentarios a la propia pregunta. Completa el [tour] y lee [ask] para más información sobre el sitio y cómo realizar mejores preguntas.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que como no estás haciendo ningún tipo de comprobación del  id de usuario, lo que vas a obtener como resultado es una combinación de todos los usuarios con todas las solicitudes. Cuando lo que quieres es que te devuelva las solicitudes correspondientes a cada usuario.

Para ello podrías hacer un `JOIN` o añadir la comprobación en el `WHERE` (además, como puede haber varias filas en solicitud, debes agrupar por el id de usuario para hacer la suma):

```
SELECT   u.pk_user, u.name, 
         u.dias_disponibles - SUM(s.n_diassolicitados) AS dias_libres 
FROM     solicitud s, sec_users u
WHERE    s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user
GROUP BY u.pk_user;
```

De ese modo te devolverá los días restantes para todos los usuarios (con su id). Si quieres que sea un usuario en particular, añade su id al `WHERE`:

```
SELECT u.dias_disponibles - SUM(s.n_diassolicitados) AS dias_libres 
FROM   solicitud s, sec_users u
WHERE  s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user 
  AND  u.pk_user = ID_DE_USUARIO;
```

Donde ID_DE_USUARIO es el ID (`pk_user`) del usuario del que quieres obtener los días libres restantes.

Puedes ver ambas consultas funcionando en este [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90625b/4).

---

Para la última parte de la pregunta (añadida posteriormente), quieres que muestre los días solicitados. Eso sería tan simple como añadir el valor de la suma como columna. Así, podrías tener algo como esto:

```
-- mostrar días disponibles, solicitados y resta para todos los trabajadores
SELECT   u.pk_user, u.name, 
         u.dias_disponibles,
         SUM(s.n_diassolicitados) AS dias_solicitados,
         u.dias_disponibles - SUM(s.n_diassolicitados) AS dias_libres 
FROM     solicitud s, sec_users u
WHERE    s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user
GROUP BY u.pk_user;

-- mostrar días disponibles, solicitados y resta para un trabajador en concreto
SELECT u.dias_disponibles,
       SUM(s.n_diassolicitados) AS dias_solicitados,
       u.dias_disponibles - SUM(s.n_diassolicitados) AS dias_libres 
FROM   solicitud s, sec_users u
WHERE  s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user 
  AND  u.pk_user = 1; -- días disponibles para Alvaro
```

que puedes ver funcionando en una actualización del [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90625b/9).

Comment: Esto asume que la relación es de 1..1; si es de 1..m o de m..n, habría que hacer algún cambio (para sumar los días solicitados en lugar de usar el valor sin más).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu contestación y perdon por l atardanza. He comprobado la primera sentencia SQL que has puesto:

Comment: SELECT u.pk_user, u.dias_disponibles - s.n_diassolicitados AS dias_libres 
FROM   solicitud s, sec_users u
WHERE  s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user

Comment: Pero no me sale nada, solo las dos columnas, sin ningun valor

Comment: @AlvaroRoman He probado las consultas que te pongo en la respuesta con las tablas que indicas (con datos ficticios) y funcionan correctamente. [Lo puedes ver online aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e61079/3).

Comment: Así si funciona, lo que pasa es que yo tengo muchas solicitudes de cada usuario. El resultado que me da a mi es los dias_libres que le quedan a cada usuario pero de cada consulta que ha hecho

Comment: He editado tu enlace. Si tu metes otra solicitud del usuario Alvaro por ejemplo, al ejecutar el sql te sale dos veces el usuario Alvaro por las dos solicitudes que ha hecho

Comment: Perfecto, esa era la parte que me faltaba. Ahora edito la respuesta cuando llegue a un ordenador.

Comment: Voy a responder a mi pregunta, creando otra duda que tengo, porque ya he solucionado la de antes

Comment: Puedes responder con lo que hiciste para resolver tu problema. Pero, si tienes una nueva duda, debes crear una nueva pregunta.

Comment: @AlvaroRoman he actualizado la respuesta para añadir los cambios que se necesitaban y los cambios que pedías en la nueva duda.